# VBA code for deleting a word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I keep a button on my ribbon for "delete word," a little, easy macro that I've been creating for years on each copy of Word. Now I have word 2013, and I did this:

1. CTRL-ALT-R, M (record a macro)
2. Select "Button"
3. Do all the right things to choose an itty bitty image & put it on the ribbon, then click "okay"
4. F8, F8 (to select the current word)
5. Delete
6. CTRL-ALT-R (stop recording the macro)

Simple, right? Then why does this blasted macro delete just a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as advertised for me. I suspect you hit F8 to close together and it missed the second one. Post the code that it recorded or just make it look like this:

```
Selection.Extend 'turn on extend mode
Selection.Extend 'extend to the current word
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```